# Moving 'people' into time slots based on answer,

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an internal database on Excel 2013 for managing people, sort of HR based.

For example, 50 people might apply for a job, but only 15 of them can be invited to interview.

What I want is some sort of automation that means that if I click a button (which might say Invite to Interview) next to the candidate's row of information, then it would automatically copy that candidate's row of data onto the next available time slot on the next sheet. The time slots would be pre-populated in column A, but the rest of the columns would be blank.

Hoping someone can help - I must admit I only have a rudimentary understanding of macros etc but I'm a fast learner.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: This is not complicated at all but still more than just a simple coding problem where you just got stuck. I think you should get a freelancer for this task, who can do this for you in a few hours. The use case is too simple, though. What if the interviewee is not available in a time slot?

Comment: Excellent point - I suppose I thought that if they weren't available for that time I would manually move them, but then if I started doing that I might as well manually move them to start with! Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do something like this. I assumed you have 2 sheets as following:

Sheet "Applicants":
[image]

Sheet "Time Slot":
[image]

```
Dim A_List As Worksheet
Dim T_List As Worksheet
Dim A_LastRow As Long
Dim T_LastRow As Long

Set A_List = Sheets("Applicants")
Set T_List = Sheets("Time Slot")
A_LastRow = A_List.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
T_LastRow = T_List.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To A_LastRow
    If A_List.Range("B" & i).Value = "Yes, Call Him" Then
        If A_List.Range("C" & i).Value <> "Yes" Then
            t = 1
            While t <= T_LastRow
                If T_List.Range("B" & t).Value = "" Then
                    A_List.Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=T_List.Range("B" & t)
                    A_List.Range("C" & i).Value = "Yes"
                    t = T_LastRow + 1
                End If
            t = t + 1
            Wend
        End If
    End If
Next
```

As a result your sheets will look like these:

Sheet "Applicants":

[image]

Sheet "Time Slot":

[image]

**WARNING: This coding do not have any error proof. You may want to add some warnings in the `IF` functions as `ELSE`**